# What file builds the pagination URL for Joomla Components?

Tags: joomla, pagination

Basically I have created a new view that shows only the puppies in list form and nothing else. Everything else is working fine except parts of the pagination.

So there are 40 puppies in this category. With 20 showing per page it shows 2 pages and works correctly. With 5 per page it shows 8 pages but doesn't work correct. When I hover over the first four page links it still shows the href to page 1 and the last four page links show href to page 2.

Here is the original / first page:

http://americasfavoritepuppybreeders.com/puppies/breed/labrador.html?tmpl=component&view=microsite

Clicking on Page 2 links goes here:

http://americasfavoritepuppybreeders.com/puppies/breed/labrador/page-1.html?tmpl=component

If I manually type in the URL that should be there, it still shows the puppies from the first page:

http://americasfavoritepuppybreeders.com/puppies/breed/labrador/page-2.html?view=microsite&tmpl=component

I need to keep the view=microsite & tmpl=component on the end of the URL.

Not sure exactly what code I should include for anyone to diagnose so please ask and I will post.

I've been working on this for 2 1/2 days now devoting my entire days to this... if anyone could help that would be so much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try create the custom template for pagination (pagination.php). Example you can find in /administrator/templates/bluestork/html/pagination.php, So, first step, in your temmplate you will create file /templates/{$your_template}/html/pagination.php. Second step, you can try use submitform() and `<input type="hidden" name="view" value="microsite" /><input type="hidden" name="tmpl" value="component" />` or adjust link in pagination how you want.

Comment: Will this override the pagination for the entire site or the pagination on that single component view?

Comment: For template. so, if you use one template, pagination will work for entire site. But you can detect the necessary component/view/layout and display necessary mode of links.